# Thumbnail images on Wordpress theme don't get CSS formatting after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a new theme based on a template theme from Wordpress (Twenty Twenty One) and there's a grid of posts made with flexbox.

Inside each post, I put on the loop

```
<figure>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
```

which is returning the correct picture, and I'm getting the following code:

```
<img width="640" height="435" src="http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" srcset="http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11.png 640w, http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11-300x204.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px" style="width:100%;height:67.97%;max-width:640px;">
```

But whenever there's an Ajax call (through filter or load more), the new posts have the following code:

```
<img width="640" height="435" src="http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" srcset="http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11.png 640w, http://georg.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Bildschirm_foto-2023-03-09-um-12.06.11-300x204.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px">
```

so, the only difference is that the posts before the Ajax call have this kind of parameter:
`style="width:100%;height:67.97%;max-width:640px;`

I suppose there's some kind of script doing the maths to find a value for % height because that's making the picture fit inside the post div.

The pictures loaded after Ajax don't have a style="" inside their tags so the picture is shown in its original size, leaking out of the container.

Is this happening because of a Wordpress setting or script? How can I assure that the pictures after the Ajax calls are also automatically resized to fit their containers?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting this style attribute as part of the HTML the server returned - or is this maybe calculated & set on the client side using JS?

Comment: @CBroe that's exactly what I needed to know, how wordpress would do it by standard but no, that's not my JS

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed that by creating a function that sets the height in % based on the ratio of the original pic

```html
function adjustImg() {
$('.grid-item figure img').each(
 function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight) {
    var srcWidth = $(this).attr('width');
    var srcHeight = $(this).attr('height');
    var ratio = (srcHeight / srcWidth);
    var width = "100%";
    var height = ratio * 100 + "%";
    $(this).css({'height': height,
'width': width,
'max-width': srcWidth});
 })};
```

and then calling the function after Ajax success.